# Gnome extensions not installing

Tags: gnome, firefox, chromium, gnome-shell-extension

I installed `Ubuntu GNOME`(eliminate `gnome` not running/wrong version) and I decided to install some extensions.

I installed  `chrome-gnome-shell` addon, and the `Firefox` addon as well. On `chromium` (eliminate `chrome` not being supported) I get a message that says :

> Your native host connector do not support following APIs:
>   notifications, update-check. Probably you should upgrade native host
>   connector or install plugins for missing APIs. Refer documentation for
>   instructions.

while on Firefox, I get a message that says :

> attempt to postMessage on disconnected port.

I think `Firefox` is a lost cause, but I think `chromium` could still be fixed. I installed the plugins needed(`cmake`, `coreutils`, `jq`, `python`) but it still says I don't have the API.

Comment: This affects me two after installing `gnome 3.20` along with `unity` on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I didn't install unity at all

Comment: It's just a workaround but I did managed to install some extensions by downloading source code and compile manually . i. g. for `Dash to dock` extension : `git clone https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock.git` then `cd dash-to-dock`, `make` and finally `make install` ([source](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/download.html))